# Ошибка при парсинге(python)

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

url = 'https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-sankt-peterburg-4079/'
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.headers)
```

Я пробовал с другим url. Сработало.
Видимо проблема в сайте. Что надо добавить?

Comment: Вам нужно добавить воды в чайник, налить чаю и посмотреть пару видосов на ютьбе, чтобы посмотреть как парсить.

Comment: Прлблема в написаний кода, headers что это?

Comment: Лишнее скопировал, уже поправил. Но даже исправленное выдаёт ошибку

Comment: У вас в коде не понятно где прописан `headers`, так же для того что бы посмотреть отдает ли сайт хоть что-то, вам достаточно будет прописать `print(res)`

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII так проверяются хэдеры ответа, ничего зазорного в этом нет и код верен. Почему нельзя использовать `res.status_code`, явно указывается какая информация нужна в выводе. Суть в том что ТС не предоставляет инфо о коде ответа. Остальное будет либо гадание, либо прямой тест по URL. что я конечно делать не буду

Comment: Не, к `status_code` у меня 0 вопросов, я не понимаю откуда он `headers` берет

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII из ответа сервера, который хранится в `res`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install fake-useragent`

```py
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

url = 'https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-sankt-peterburg-4079/'
res = requests.get(url,
                   headers={
                       'User-Agent': ua.firefox
                   }
                   )
print(res.status_code)
print(res.headers)
# 200
# {'Date': 'Sun, 03 Apr 2022 20:34:20 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent', 'Server-Timing': "type;desc='cache'", 'Server': 'gis', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=604800', 'X-DC': 'nord.router-ru-nord02', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Decepticon': '0', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

> Запустите пару раз. `fake-useragent` при первом запуске выдает исключение